# Lubuntu 16.04 doesn't automatically log in if monitor is not plugged in?

Tags: lubuntu, lightdm, auto-login

I want the machine to automatically log in so that it can start processes as the main user on boot. I have the settings set to auto login:

/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

```
[Seat:*]
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=kota
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

When I have the monitor plugged in it behaves as expected, but when I have it unplugged, it doesn't log in until I plug in the monitor and sometimes just stays on lightdm. I'm using the proprietary Nvidia driver.

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?